# As partner community user, Unable to access Dashboard as logged in user

Tags: reporting, dashboard, partner-communities

Getting the following error message, when trying to access dashboard as logged in user, as a Partner community user
The source report is based on a report type that is inaccessible to the dashboard's running user.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried going to the folder that contains the report, right clicking on the right side, and sharing it with the roles, Internal and portal subordinates?

[image: Share]